# Possible to use different sending email addresses from hudson/jenkins? (or is there only one global build email for all projects per intrance?)

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I am using hudson right now for various projects.  The CI server runs several disparate projects and I would prefer to get emails from the corresponding domain for that project (I have multiple ventures going and would prefer not to run VMs or 2 machines just to run another instance of hudson)

If this is not possible no big deal - I was just hoping that each project could be published from its own email account.

But I have not seen a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that even the most advanced (to my knowledge) Jenkins e-mail plugin - [Email-Ext Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) - does not provide such functionality.

You may, however, use that plugin to play with your subject line per job, so that you may include the domain info as the subject prefix.

Comment: Yes, this is what I found - I was just trying to see if there were others.  It seems like a reasonable thing to add but not critical.  I had already set subject lines for each project of course.